# Flask response is in str(JSON) how to convert it into JSON

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to return a JSON response from my flask application.

But instead i get something like this while hitting API:

> "{"data": "\n\nDell laptops are the perfect way to stay connected and productive on the go. With a variety of models to choose from, there's a Dell laptop for every budget. From the lightweight and affordable Inspiron series to the high-powered XPS line, Dell has a laptop for every need.", "status": "success"}"

What I get while printing internally is :

> {"data": "\n\nDell laptops are the perfect way to stay connected and productive on the go. With a variety of models to choose from, there's a Dell laptop for every budget. From the lightweight and affordable Inspiron series to the high-powered XPS line, Dell has a laptop for every need.", "status": "success"}

My code:

```
from crypt import methods
from warnings import catch_warnings
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import flask
import openai
from flask_restful import Api,Resource
import base64
import json


#Init
app =   Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

#To return in JSON format
class tojson:
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, 
            sort_keys=True)

#OPENAI CREDENTIALS
openai.api_key = "sk-"


#Functions

class advert_data(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            request_body=request.json
            A=request_body["data"]
            adprompt = "Write an advertisement for " + A


            
            response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-002",
            prompt=adprompt,
            temperature=0.7,
            max_tokens=70,
            top_p=1.0,
            n=1
            )
            json_advert = json.loads(str(response))
            advert_output = json_advert['choices'][0]['text']
            
            #response json formatting
            response=tojson()
            response.data=advert_output
            response.status="success"
            toreturn=(response.toJSON())
            

            print(toreturn)
            
            return  (((toreturn))),200
        except:
            return ({"ERROR":Exception}),500




#Mapping
api.add_resource(advert_data,'/advert/data',methods=['POST'])
#api.add_resource(advert_image,'/advert/data',methods=['POST'])




if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=8081)
```

I tried jsonifying the String, It didn't help though.

how to solve this

Comment: you are using  `json.dumps()` to convert your dict object to string. What else did you expect? You can load this string back to json using  `json.loads()`

Comment: Also, sending back a string would probably make the content type as text/plain. You need to set the content type header to `application/json`

Comment: Yeah I got it, i totally got spaced out with the json.dumps(). Thanks!!!